# convert a string that is utf-8 code to real unicode string

Tags: python, string, unicode

now I have the string of `unicode` code like `"\u8fea\u514b"` ,how do I convert it to the real `unicode` object like `u"\u8fea\u514b"` in python.

Comment: Looking at the docs never hurts - [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#unicode-howto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> s = "\u8fea\u514b"
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
>>> s.decode('unicode-escape')
u'\u8fea\u514b'
# OR
>>> new_s = unicode(s, 'unicode-escape')
>>> type(new_s)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> new_s
u'\u8fea\u514b'
```

You can type cast from string to Unicode unsing `Unicode` class.

```
class unicode(basestring)
 |  unicode(string [, encoding[, errors]]) -> object
 |
 |  Create a new Unicode object from the given encoded string.
 |  encoding defaults to the current default string encoding.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `string.decode('unicode-escape')`

```
>>> "\u8fea\u514b".decode('unicode-escape')
u'\u8fea\u514b'
```